# How to hide buttons based on condition in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I  want to hide buttons based on condition, how can i achieve this in reactjs,
condition is :

```
abc[3]
{
0->id:121
   name:asdas
1->id:2321
   name:sdasd
}
```

and button code looks like below , can i add condition like below if so whats the condition do i replace with condition

```
{condition ? (
    <Button
                id="discover-vnf-button"
                icon="ic_find"
                disabled={this.state.disableVnfDiscover}
              />
 ) : null}
```

if array [abc] doesnot contain any nodes then i want button to be disabled

Comment: This link help with you https://codepen.io/joshbivens/pen/LNLKor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let say your array[abc]=this.state.abc

```
{this.state.abc.length!=0 ?<Button id="discover-vnf-button" icon="ic_find" disabled={this.state.disableVnfDiscover} />: null}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the condition to display Button tag only if your array has data like below-

```
{this.state.abc && <Button id="discover-vnf-button" icon="ic_find"></Button>}
```

or

```
{this.state.abc.length > 0 && <Button id="discover-vnf-button" icon="ic_find"></Button>}
```

Assuming abc is a state variable.

Comment: I'm already disabling the button, i need button to be hided, 

and how to check an array contains details or not

Comment: Please mark the answer as completed if it helped you, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function Demo() {
  arr = [1];
  return arr.length > 0 ? (
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      color="primary"
      disableElevation
      disabled={arr.length == 0}
    >
      Disable elevation
    </Button>
  ) : null;
}
```

Just change your condition `arr.length > 0`. (Ex: this.state.arr.length > 0)